# Неправильно отображается текст svg в safari

Tags: svg, safari, illustrator

Сделал свой [сайт](https://rybn1kov.ru)
в tilda, логотип экспортировал из ai в svg. Однако в safari слетают шрифты, в chrome все ок. Перепробовал все опции экспорта – ни на что не повлияло. Хэлп!

Safari

[image: Safari]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Очевидно, svg-файл ссылается на какой-то неведомый шрифт TrajanPro3-Regular, взяться которому неоткуда. Или внедряйте шрифт в svg-файл, или преобразуйте текст в кривые

Comment: про кривые не догадался, благодарю!